# iPhone retina 4-inch Simulator with Storyboard set to 3.5 inch

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, tableview

i'm testing my application but if i run it with "[image: iPhone retina 4-inch Simulator]" and the storyboard is set to 3,5 inch the result is the the following. Why?

This is a ViewController with an UITableView inside. Tha view controller background color is blue.

What is the matter?

Comment: What was your expected result?

Comment: check autolayout in xcode.

Comment: Did you set your ViewController background colour to blue…? This might also happen if you have static cells in your tableView ...

Comment: I expect the same result that i have when the storyboard is set to 4 inch and the device is an iPhone 4 inch. In that case i don't see the background color because table completely fills the view

Answer (score 1):

Setting the storaybaord to 3.5 is only just a simulation. But it might change your AutoLayout in the process. So if you want a quick solution try doing following.

select the viewcontroller in your Storyboard and, tick both options "Under top bars" , "Under bottm bars"

[image]

Comment: These options are selected but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved disabling "Use Autolayout" in Interface Builder Document of Main.storyboard.

[image]

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You should add Autolayout constraints to your TableView so that it hugs the Top and Bottom Layout Guides of its parent UIViewController.
[image: Top & Bottom Layout Guides]